# Returning a Number from a string with a predefined length in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have an address field like

```
'12345 dummycity 14'
'NL - 54321 City'
'12 City4  32154'
```

I want to extract only the substring where there are 5 numeric characters in a row.

Anybody has a clue how to extract this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such string processing is a little tricky in SQL Server, but `patindex()` does much of the work for you:

```
select left(stuff(str, 1, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', str) - 1, ''), 5)
from (values ('NL - 54321 City')) v(str)
```

Comment: that was fast, thank u very much! I was on the good way but didn't come up to define my pattern as [0-9] 5 times!